# WPF Extended ToolKit DatetimePicker need to display the time from 8AM - 5PM ONLY

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit, wpf-4.0

WPF Extended ToolKit DatetimePicker need to display the time from 8AM - 5PM ONLY.
Please help, Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer,`<extToolkit:DateTimePicker.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type extToolkit:TimePicker}">

                            <Setter Property="StartTime"
                                    Value="07:00"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="EndTime"
                                    Value="17:00"></Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Style.Resources>
                </Style>
            </extToolkit:DateTimePicker.Style>`
 Thank You.